# Do line endings distinctions apply for html forms?

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I know that the line endings used for files vary depending on the OS. I was wondering, if a user pastes text into a http form input such as a textarea, does the line ending character(s) for what gets sent depend on the OS in the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the browser should canonicalize the line endings.

Comment: I was considering asking what the standard is but the link in the comments covers that, so...answer approved!

Comment: I was considering googling for the standard but wanted more coffee first.

Comment: However, client-side the line endings CAN vary.  This is problematic if you're trying to enforce a max length in a textarea.  The JavaScript in the browser such as Firefox will use \n by default even when run on Windows.  The server can then convert to \r\n and then you're in a situation where the client check said the input was of proper length, but then the server says it is too long!