# New lines and browser/OS compatability

Tags: java, browser, newline

I have a form that accepts a list of values, each value being listed on a separate line of textArea. In my Servlet, I am tokenizing the string I recieve from that textArea based on the new line characters "\r\n", like so:

```
String[] partNumberList = originalPartNumberString.split("\r\n");
```

This appears to work fine. I get an array of values as expected. I believe this is because the browser handles standardizing the way newlines are sent to the server, regardless of what OS / browser the form data is being sent from ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760282/do-line-endings-distinctions-apply-for-html-forms)). I've tested in IE, Firefox, Chrome ... everything appears to work fine with that and I feel pretty confident about it.

After receiving the values on the server side, I then use those values for some looks ups, etc., then I write them back to the textArea for the response. In order to do so, I am writing it back in the same fashion I am receiving it ... I just build a new String, and separate each value with a "\r\n". I then set the value of the textArea to that String.

```
StringBuffer invalidReturnPartList = new StringBuffer("");

for (int i = 0; i < requestedPartList.length; i++)
{
    invalidReturnPartList.append(requestedPartList[i]);
    invalidReturnPartList.append("\r\n");
}

return invalidReturnPartList.toString();
```

This also tests OK for me in all browsers I have tried. However, I'm just nervous about whether I'm covering all my bases here ... if someone is running a Mac, will the "\r\n" translate correctly on their browser? What about Linux? I would think everything would be handled in the browser, but I am just not sure here... so my question is, does this look right to you, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question here.

Since the values of the textArea are form data, and the form is submitted to the server with Content Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", the new lines are converted to "CR LF" by the browser before submitting to the server according to the HTML spec (see http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1).

So in this case, my code should work consistently, regardless of browser or OS.

However, if I were trying to implement the same code client-side (let's say, with JavaScript), perhaps to validate the form before submission ... that may be a different story. Since the form data has not been canonicalized at this point, it is most likely dependent on whatever the platform/browser uses for new lines. In that case, I would probably need to check not only for "\r\n", but also for "\r" and "\n".

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the HTTP protocol definition, you'll find that:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF
>   as the end-of-line marker for all
>   protocol elements except the
>   entity-body (see appendix 19.3 for
>   tolerant applications). The
>   end-of-line marker within an
>   entity-body    is defined by its
>   associated media type, as described in
>   section 3.7.

But that is not valid for the body. I assume you send the form information with a post request, so I assume the content type text/plain is used, and in that case I think the following applies:

> 3.7.1 Canonicalization and Text Defaults
>
> Internet media types are registered
>   with a canonical form. An
>   entity-body transferred via HTTP
>   messages MUST be represented in the
>   appropriate canonical form prior to
>   its transmission except for    "text"
>   types, as defined in the next
>   paragraph.
>
> When in canonical form, media
>   subtypes of the "text" type use CRLF
>   as    the text line break. HTTP
>   relaxes this requirement and allows
>   the    transport of text media with
>   plain CR or LF alone representing a
>   line    break when it is done
>   consistently for an entire
>   entity-body. HTTP    applications MUST
>   accept CRLF, bare CR, and bare LF as
>   being    representative of a line
>   break in text media received via HTTP.

That means, it would be okay for a browser to send you UNIX style endlines.

(Both paragraphs are from http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Comment: I see your point. However, I think when the form is submitted, its submitted with Content Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

This post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760282/do-line-endings-distinctions-apply-for-html-forms) references a document (http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1) which seems to imply that line breaks are always replaced with "CR LF" when a form is submitted with the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type ... "Line breaks, as in multi-line text field values, are represented as CR LF pairs, i.e. `%0D%0A'."

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought the content type also started with text/* . Well, then your code should work ;)

Comment: This post is old, but still, I wanted to give you some credit ... I just gave you an upvote for this answer. I ended up answering my own question, but I couldn't have without this answer to put me on the right track.