# explode textarea php (at new lines)

Tags: php, explode

can I do:

```
explode("\n", $_POST['thetextarea']);
```

and have it work on all platforms? (The question I am asking is will it ever be \r\n and not just \n")

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I am saving $_POST['thetextarea'] to a mysql database VARCHAR 255. It seems \r\n is converted to \n.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760282/do-line-endings-distinctions-apply-for-html-forms

Comment: If the text field contains `\r\n` then spliting on newlines would still work, and just keep extraneous carriage returns in the lines.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This will do the trick given `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`:

```
preg_split('/\r\n|[\r\n]/', $_POST['thetextarea'])
```

Comment: Yup. Worked for me too, not the \r\n one.

Comment: with a bit difference worked for me, double quote instead of single "/\r\n|[\r\n]/" and I don't know why

Answer (score 25):

You should use:

```
explode("\r\n", $_POST['thetextarea']);
```

It will always be the same.

Browsers and other user-agents will make sure they are :-)

See http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1 for more info.

Comment: Not all user agents are browsers however.

Comment: @mario: also according to the HTML5 spec (draft I know) lines are terminated by `CRLF`. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-textarea-element if I'm correct

Comment: new link is http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-textarea-element

Answer (score 12):

You could also use the `PHP_EOL` constant:

```
explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST['thetextarea']);
```

Comment: wouldn't PHP_EOL just use the linebreak of the current platform? If so, you don't want it here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$text = trim($_POST['textareaname']);
$text = nl2br($text);
```

Comment: "It's important to remember that this function does NOT replace newlines with <br> tags. Rather, it inserts a <br> tag before each newline, but it still preserves the newlines themselves!" - guy at php.net manual